# Debugging in Visual Studio with iOS Safari Emulator

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, safari, emulation

As the title says, I want to know if there's a way to completely emulate the experience of iOS Safari in Visual Studio?

Comment: You'll have to be little more specific. What do you intend to achieve by `emulating` a browser in Visual Studio?

Comment: The goal is to emulate an iPhone using safari so I can get the 500 error from my API on localhost. It's currently only breaking for iOS on Safari specifically.

Comment: That's an error on the server. Debug your server not the browser. Record the full request to your server (headers, cookies, etc) ) and then use something like Postman to replay.

Comment: But it only breaks when the call is coming specifically from an iPhone on Safari. Is there a way to post that information in the header to enact that information being passed to the server??

Comment: im currently doing something similar, i'll let you know if i come across anything. or have you found a solution by now?

Comment: store the request that hits the server , then you can just send it with curl , you don't really need as pointed out emulating browser to resolve server error, just store the incoming request and reuse directly , curl or postman whatever suits to send it , that should do the job, or look at the logs that serve the API